# Сделать необязательным поле ArrayField в Django модели

Tags: django

Написал класс, хочу добавлять в базу postgeSQL `character varying[]` для этого нашёл `ArrayField`. Но форма вечно просит заполнить это поле. При добавлении в `null=True` в CharField в ArrayField или сам ArrayField ничего не происходит.

Как Пофиксить ?

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
open_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
restrict_ip = models.BooleanField()
ip = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
    size=8
)
valid_to_date = models.DateField()
restrict_methods = models.BooleanField()
allowed_methods = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
    size=8,
)
forbidden_methods = ArrayField(
    models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
    size=8,
)


class KeyForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ApiKey
    fields = [
        'description', 'open_key', 'secret_key', 'restrict_ip',
        'ip', 'valid_to_date', 'restrict_methods', 'allowed_methods', 'forbidden_methods'
    ]

    widgets = {
        'description': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'description'
        }),
        'open_key': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'open_key'
        }),
        'secret_key': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'secret_key'
        }),
        'restrict_ip': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
        }),
        'ip': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'ip',
            'required': False
        }),
        'valid_to_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'valid_to_date'
        }),
        'restrict_methods': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={
        }),
        'allowed_methods': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'allowed_methods'
        }),
        'forbidden_methods': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': ATTR_CLASS_DEFAULT,
            'placeholder': 'forbidden_methods'
        }),
    }

    labels = {
        'description': 'description',
        'open_key': 'open_key',
        'secret_key': 'secret_key',
        'restrict_ip': 'restrict_ip',
        'ip': 'ip',
        'valid_to_date': 'valid_to_date:',
        'restrict_methods': 'restrict_methods',
        'allowed_methods': 'allowed_methods',
        'forbidden_methods': 'forbidden_methods'
    }

    error_messages = {
        'description': {
            'required': REQUIRED_ERROR,
            'max_length': MAX_LENGTH_ERROR.format(255),
        },
        'open_key': {
            'required': REQUIRED_ERROR,
            'max_length': MAX_LENGTH_ERROR.format(128),
        },
        'secret_key': {
            'required': REQUIRED_ERROR,
            'max_length': MAX_LENGTH_ERROR.format(14),
        },
        'valid_to_date': {
            'required': REQUIRED_ERROR,
            'max_length': MAX_LENGTH_ERROR.format(255),
        },
    }

    help_texts = {
        'valid_to_date': 'Формат даты "ГГГГ-ММ-ДД"',
        'ip': 'Вводить через запятую: 0.0.0.0,192.168.1.1',
        'allowed_methods': 'Вводить через запятую: a,b,c',
        'forbidden_methods': 'Вводить через запятую: a,b,c'
    }
```

Comment: `blank=True` пробовали?

Comment: Сработало... Спасибо, можете сделать как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы форма не ругалась, укажи `blank=True` в сам `ArrayField`, а не в `СharField` находящийся внутри этого `ArrayField`

`null=True` устанавливает `NULL` (вместо `NOT NULL`) для столбца в вашей БД.

`blank=True` определяет, обязательно ли поле для заполнено в формах. Это касается и форм в `django.contrib.admin` и ваших собственных пользовательских форм. Если `blank=True`, то заполнение поля обязательно, если же `blank=False`, то это поле может быть не заполнено.

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    open_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    secret_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    restrict_ip = models.BooleanField()
    ip = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8,
        blank=True
    )
    valid_to_date = models.DateField()
    restrict_methods = models.BooleanField()
    allowed_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8,
        blank=True
    )
    forbidden_methods = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True),
        size=8,
        blank=True
    )
```